# Resize macOS partition gaining from Windows partition resized

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, window-manager

This question is about macOS BigSur 11.6.1 w/ Boot Camp Windows 10.

The HDD was partitioned for macOS and Windows 10. Since the macOS upgrade to 12/13 needs bigger size, I resized the Windows partition and spared 20GB in order to combine this unformatted partition into macOS.

While trying **Disk Utility**, I cannot find an option to combine that partition to macOS (APFS container + volume).

Would it possible to do this with **Disk Utility** or do I have to use command line? Or would it be better to do this in Windows using e.g. mini tools? I am concerned whether this software can successfully recognize/resize the macOS APFS container system.

Comment: *NEVER* play around with partitions on the Windows side!

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list` to your question. Be sure to use code tags. At the moment it's not clear what partitions are on your disk. The order they are present on the disk will determine what can be expanded, and how.

Comment: Normally, `diskutil list` should show `disk0` has three partitions followed by free space. The partitions should be `EFI`, `Apple_APFS` and `Microsoft Basic Data`, in that order.

Comment: thank you all for your comments, I finally did it as following: 1. Resize with mini tool but shift the left bar to right and resize the W partition, then restart & apply. again restart to macOS, Disk U saw the unallocated space, and expanded. Now I got upgrade to Monterey. /BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used a Big Sur version of the Boot Camp Assistant to install Windows 10 on your Mac, then Windows 10 was installed to UEFI boot. This is based on the information given in following Apple websites.

- [Install Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468)
- [macOS Big Sur is compatible with these computers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238)

Basically, you need to move the free space to occur before the Windows partition.

> Note: The answer below applies to Macs which UEFI boot Windows. If you have an older Mac which legacy BIOS boots Windows, then you should not use the answer below.

Your question is basically a duplicate of the question [Missing around 20 GB of Space on MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432199/missing-around-20-gb-of-space-on-macbook), at least in terms of a solution.

To add the remaining free space back to the partition containing macOS, the partition containing Windows would have to be first moved to the end of the drive. There are third party tools that can move Windows partitions. However, not all are compatible with macOS. According to [the other post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432199/missing-around-20-gb-of-space-on-macbook), there are two possible compatible free tools available. These tools are outlined below.

- [GNOME Partition Editor (GParted)](https://gparted.org/). A Linux based bootable USB flash drive can be created containing this tool. After booting from the flash drive, the GParted tool can be used to move the Windows partition. If you [build the bootable USB flash drive using the zip file downloaded from GParted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271739/how-to-make-and-use-an-usb-stick-with-gparted-that-will-boot-on-a-mac/354805#354805), then both a keyboard and a mouse (or similar device) is required. One disadvantage is the keyboard and/or mouse may need to be wired to use this tool. However, if you can boot from a [Ubuntu installer](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview) flash drive, then only use of a mouse is required. One advantage is this tool does not have to be installed into Windows.
- [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com). This tool is installed into Windows. To move Windows, the Mac reboots and performs the move without user interaction. One advantage is any existing keyboard and mouse (or similar device) can be used. One disadvantage is this tool has to be installed in Windows and therefore will still exist on the drive after you are finished moving Windows.

> Note: Before attempting to move the Windows partition, the Windows [`chkdsk`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk) command should be applied to the NTFS volume in this partition. This can be accomplished by booting to [Windows Recovery Environment (Windows RE)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-10) and entering the command below.

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

---

Once Windows is moved, the command below can be used to add the free space to the macOS partition (`disk0s2`).

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

### Similar Questions

- [Missing around 20 GB of Space on MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432199/missing-around-20-gb-of-space-on-macbook)
- [How to add to macOS (free space) from diskutil list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434419/how-to-add-to-macos-free-space-from-diskutil-list)
- [Can I delete a partition and leave the space unallocated in Monterey?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438561/can-i-delete-a-partition-and-leave-the-space-unallocated-in-monterey)

Comment: Thanks!
I don't have the credit to upvote your reply thus just select yours as solution. As comment above under my Q, the key issue is to spare the space at the beginning of the W partition, so it directly adjoined to end of macOS, thus Disk Utility can find it and expand it.