# Big Sur - How can I increase Bootcamp's partition size?

Tags: macos, windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I installed Boot Camp last month on my Mac (Big Sur/macOS 11.7.10) so I could run Windows 10. I created a partition of a modest size, assuming that it would be adequate. I've since realized that that I didn't allocate enough storage space.

I looked at increasing the partition's size with Disk Utility, but it says, "This volume cannot be resized." (See screenshot.) Boot Camp Assistant doesn't offer an option to change it either.

I did find some third-party applications that claim to elegantly allow users to manage Boot Camp's partition size, but they're not sold at a price that I can afford. I couldn't find any free solutions either.

**How can I increase Bootcamp's partition size on Big Sur? Are there any trustworthy free or low-cost solutions? Any good or undocumented workarounds?**

[image: Screenshot of the Disk Utility app displaying partition information, along with highlighted text indicating that the volume cannot be resized]

Comment: start over .....

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Resize macOS partition gaining from Windows partition resized](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449958/resize-macos-partition-gaining-from-windows-partition-resized)? If not and your question gets flagged as a duplicate, then post a comment explaining why not.

Comment: Hi, @DavidAnderson. That other question is for a similar, but otherwise different issue, and the answer doesn't address my need. The Q&A there discussed modifying or moving the partition(s) for macOS, not BOOTCAMP/Windows. My question is asking about increasing the size of latter.

Comment: EJ: I posted an answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388/can-i-resize-a-bootcamp-partition-without-reinstalling-windows/467276#467276).